# How to Verify that a String Index Is an Integer?

Tags: python, string

I am writing a function that will count the number of lines that have a number as the first character in the string. However, I am a little stuck as to how to see if l[0] is a string without crashing the whole program.
Here is the function thus far...

```
def leading_digits(source):
    sum = 0
    lines = source.split("\n")
    for l in lines:
        #How to verify that l[0] is an integer?
        #If this check proves true, sum += 1
    return sum
```

Comment: Are you checking for a digit, or checking that the index is a legal index for the string? If it's just checking for the string being non-empty and the first character being a digit, you'd just do `if l and l[0].isdigit():` which verifies non-empty first (so no `IndexError` indexing to `0` in an empty string), then checks if the first character is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try/except`:

```
def leading_digits(source):
    sum = 0
    lines = source.split("\n")
    for l in lines:
        try:
          int(l[0])
        except ValueError:
          continue
　　　　　sum += 1
    return sum
```